# Functions without interface

Tags: delphi, interface

The following looks syntactically right and compiles fine.

```
unit MyAPI;

interface
// function Min(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
// function Max(X, Y: Integer): Integer;

implementation

function Min(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if X < Y then Min := X else Min := Y;
end;

function Max(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
begin
  if X > Y then Max := X else Max := Y;
end;

end.
```

I would like to do the same for 50 more functions, typically facade functions for a dynamic library I'm building. These 50 functions all have a small body and just call internal code then convert the data for C-style calls through the output DLL.

For this reason I would like to make the economy of writing the interface part.

```
unit MyAPI;

interface
uses Optimizer;

implementation

function Min(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
var
  optimizer: TOptimizer;
begin
  optimizer := TOptimizer.Create;
  Min := optimizer.Min(X,Y);
end; stdcall;

...

end.
```

Is this OK, or bad practice? What other options do I have?

Comment: So are you saying you don't want to write the interface code? That is fine, it just means that the functions will not be visible outside of the unit they are defined in.

Comment: `Min` and `Max` are already declared in `Math` unit. Try to avoid duplication of RTL utilities.

Comment: @LURD - I'm guessing that that's an example to show the concept.

Comment: In your second code example you should make Min a class function if possible so you don't have to create an instance of TOptimizer.

Comment: I cannot see a question here. I don't understand why the title refers to `inline`. There's no inline here. Please edit to make it clear what you are asking.

Comment: Question updated sorry.

Comment: Still no question. Please ask a direct question.

Comment: Please check the last sentence.
"Is this OK, or bad practice?" Yes/No

"What other options do I have?" First option, Second option...

Answer (score 3):

Besides the evident memory leak in the second example (no destruction of variable `optimizer`), mainly based on what you are asking, there is a difference between declaring the functions in the interface section or not.

Functions not declared in the interface section can only be used within the same unit and cannot be called from other units using that unit.

Functions declared in the interface section can be used outside the unit.

It is not a matter of economizing lines, both options are semantically different and it is a decision to hide the function to the outside world or not.

Comment: All functions in the question return values. You can assign to the implicit function return variable either using `Result` in extended syntax or using the function name.

Comment: Oops didn't see that Min was the name of the function... editing

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see why there is a memory leak. 

I am obviously not a Delphi specialist, but it seems similar to C++ concept of allocating memory on the stack (object automatically dies at the end of the Min function). See how they use the Create keyword in this example. 
http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Constructor
Or am I wrong?

Comment: @John - Delphi never assumes objects go out of scope for you, you need to explicitly `.free` them, preferably in a `try..finally` block. The only exception to this is interfaces

Comment: As @Matt pointed, Delphi don't have a Garbage Collector for object (only reference counting for interfaces) and every construction should be followe with a destruction, for that reason is very recomendable to NEVER return an instance of an object created within a function (except for constructors) and (almost) allways try to have the construction in the same block code than the destruction. Beware, C++ has the same problem, only lenguages with Garbage Collection (Java, C#, python, etc) free the objects when all the variables referencing it goes out of scope.

Comment: @John the example you have found in DelphiBasics has the same memory leak issue. Please reffer to this article http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/a/memoryleak.htm to a better understanding on that subject

Comment: In C++ memory leaks only potentially occur when you use `new` operator to construct an object (dynamic allocation). If you directly use the constructor (static allocation) it is destructed when it goes out of scope. You can verify that with the debugger by putting a breakpoint into the destructor.

Comment: Can't remember exactly the c++ languaje, but the use of the constructors in delphi is exactly the same thing than using the "new" in c++ (dynamic allocation).I don't know what do you mean with "constructor (static allocation)" in C++ but if you are talking about using static (class) methods, in delphi is the same thing, you can define a class method and it would be accessible without the nneeding of constructing an object (like the C++ static methods) and in this case nothing should be freed.

Answer (score 3):

The meanings of the `interface` and `implementation` section are quite distinct. In a nutshell - the implementation is the actual code, and it needs whatever is required to make it run. Obviously, code that is not implemented will not work :)

The `interface` section is the part of the unit that can be seen and used by other units.
If your whole program is a single unit, then there's absolutely no need of an `interface` definition.

If you need to use your code from outside the unit, as you imply (façade functions for a dynamic library) you should list those functions in the `interface` part.

If you are aware of object oriented concepts, this is analogous to a private / public definition. Anything declared in the `interface` is public, while everything else is private. The `interface`/`implementation` separation is, more or less, poor man's encapsulation.